# Forge functions inside a tab

Tags: trigger.io

Is it possible to use forge functions like `request.ajax()` and `prefs.get()` inside  `tabs.openWithOptions()` opening a local html file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the modal view that opens when using the tabs module is designed to act more like a browser window and not allow access to forge methods.

Is there a reason you want to open a local page in a modal view? You should be able to use Javascript/CSS to display a modal dialog in your app without navigating to a different page.

Comment: The reason why i would like to do this instead of using JS/CSS, 
is the feeling of the modal view, which is much more like a native app than the JS/CSS-version.

thanks
Henrik